# Angular Page Partials Don't allow <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, document.write

So long story short, I've tried a billion ways to put a parameter into a string as text, with no solution to be had. I decided that instead I might use a Document.Write to cheat and print a global variable as HTML... However, I discovered that an HTML partial in AngularJS, won't let me use and  tags on the partial page.

Example:

```
$routeProvider
           .when('/score', {templateUrl: 'partials/score.html'})
```

Then, on score.html, I can't put in this statement. It simply does not execute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("This is a test");
            //document.write("This is a test"+$rootScope.variable);
</script>
```

I've also tried window.document.write, even ngApp.document.write. It just doesn't seem to write at all. On network view it looks like the JS isn't running at all. Why? How?

EDIT: I know about data binding. It doesn't work inside an attribute string... I don't know why. This doesn't not work:

```
<div addthis-toolbox class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style social-width" style="width: 150 px">
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" addthis:title="My score is {{score}}"></a> 
</div>
```

EDIT2: Actually, I think that there might be a directive overriding the div class. Here is the angular directive in question:

```
myApp.directive('addthisToolbox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            // Dynamically init for performance reason
            // Safe for multiple calls, only first call will be processed (loaded css/images, popup injected)
            // http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#configuration-url
            // http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381221-optimizing-addthis-performance
            addthis.init();
            // Ajax load (bind events)
            // http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#rendering-js-toolbox
            // http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/548551-help-on-call-back-using-ajax-i-lose-share-buttons
            addthis.toolbox($(element).get());
        }
    }
});
```

How does one pass data bindings into an attribute if it's got a directive affecting it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Usually you print variables in your partials with `{{varname}}` where `varname` is attached to `$scope` on your controller.

Comment: {{varname}} doesn't work inside attributes, this doesn't work:

    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" addthis:title="My score is {{score}}"></a>

Comment: Data binding should work inside attributes -- it's a pretty common method for doing things like <a href="{{link}}">. Post the rest of your code and maybe we can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: When it reaches `addthis`, is your title string wrong?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/i6NT0qGd Really, that's it. When I hit share for Twitter it comes up as {{score}} instead of as a number.

Comment: No, addthis:title works if I don't put a binding in there.

Comment: The code you've shown in pastebin looks fine. What is this "addthis:title" thing, is it an Angular directive? You need to show the code for that (or at least explain what it is). It's also better to edit your question and include the code here, rather than on some other site.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I think there might be a directive overriding the bindings somehow. Edited the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use javascript inside a page with type="text/ng-template"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267106/how-to-use-javascript-inside-a-page-with-type-text-ng-template)